# Cucumber, RVM, Ruby 2.0.0 and 1_8_7 constant Error

Tags: ruby, cucumber, rvm

I have done a simple `$ gem install cucumber` on RVM with Ruby 2.0.0 (on FreeBSD 9.1-i386 GENERIC), and, when I run `$ cucumber` I have the following error:

```
uninitialized constant Cucumber::RUBY_1_8_7 (NameError)
/home/black/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@cucumber/gems/cucumber-1.3.2/lib/cucumber/constantize.rb:36:in `constantize_name'
/home/black/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@cucumber/gems/cucumber-1.3.2/lib/cucumber/constantize.rb:12:in `block in constantize'
/home/black/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@cucumber/gems/cucumber-1.3.2/lib/cucumber/constantize.rb:11:in `each'
/home/black/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@cucumber/gems/cucumber-1.3.2/lib/cucumber/constantize.rb:11:in `constantize'
/home/black/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@cucumber/gems/cucumber-1.3.2/lib/cucumber/runtime/support_code.rb:73:in `load_programming_language'
/home/black/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@cucumber/gems/cucumber-1.3.2/lib/cucumber/runtime/support_code.rb:194:in `programming_language_for'
/home/black/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@cucumber/gems/cucumber-1.3.2/lib/cucumber/runtime/support_code.rb:178:in `load_file'
/home/black/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@cucumber/gems/cucumber-1.3.2/lib/cucumber/runtime/support_code.rb:83:in `block in load_files!'
/home/black/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@cucumber/gems/cucumber-1.3.2/lib/cucumber/runtime/support_code.rb:82:in `each'
/home/black/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@cucumber/gems/cucumber-1.3.2/lib/cucumber/runtime/support_code.rb:82:in `load_files!'
/home/black/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@cucumber/gems/cucumber-1.3.2/lib/cucumber/runtime.rb:183:in `load_step_definitions'
/home/black/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@cucumber/gems/cucumber-1.3.2/lib/cucumber/runtime.rb:42:in `run!'
/home/black/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@cucumber/gems/cucumber-1.3.2/lib/cucumber/cli/main.rb:47:in `execute!'
/home/black/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@cucumber/gems/cucumber-1.3.2/bin/cucumber:13:in `<top (required)>'
/home/black/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@cucumber/bin/cucumber:23:in `load'
/home/black/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@cucumber/bin/cucumber:23:in `<main>'
/home/black/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@cucumber/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `eval'
/home/black/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@cucumber/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `<main>'
```

Have you got a simillar issue?

Thanks by advance for your help.

PS : my gems list is:

```
bigdecimal (1.2.0)
builder (3.2.2)
bundler (1.3.5)
cucumber (1.3.2)
diff-lcs (1.2.4)
gherkin (2.12.0)
io-console (0.4.2)
json (1.7.7)
minitest (4.3.2)
multi_json (1.7.7)
psych (2.0.0)
rake (10.0.4, 0.9.6)
rdoc (4.0.0)
rubygems-bundler (1.1.1)
rvm (1.11.3.7)
test-unit (2.0.0.0)
```

Comment: is this empty directory? are there any files? maybe `Gemfile`?

Comment: I run it from examples' sub-directories of Cucumber git repository. So, there are files, but no Gemfile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code that breaks was removed in master, try:

```
bundle init # create a Gemfile
echo "gem 'cucumber', :git => 'https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber.git'"
bundle install
bundle exec cucumber
```

if you want to use any extra gems this way, you need to put them into `Gemfile` you can read more about it and `bundler` visit it's site: http://gembundler.com

Comment: This bug is now fixed in the latest 1.3.3 release. The master branch is currently moving towards Cucumber 2.0 release so there may be gotchas using it in production. YMMV.

Answer (score 0):

looks like a bug in `Cucumber` version `1.3.2`, it should be relatively to fix.

1. Find `cucumber/constantize`:

   ```
   gem which cucumber/constantize
   ```

   in your case it should be:

   ```
   /home/black/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@cucumber/gems/cucumber-1.3.2/lib/cucumber/constantize.rb
   ```
2. Edit this file and add this text on the beginning:

   ```
   require 'cucumber/platform'
   ```

Comment: there is a check `unless defined?(Cucumber::VERSION)` in `/home/black/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@cucumber/gems/cucumber-1.3.2/lib/cucumber/platform.rb` remove it and one of the double `end` from the end, rubys `require` takes care of avoiding double loading.